# how to set autoexec.txt in exe file in vdos

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I have a problem using the dos emulator program.

exe and database paths as follows :

1. Path exe : C:\Util\CAMUS.EXE
2. Path Database : C:\STACK\ADMIN & C:\STACK\NOW

VDos and other files I put in the util folder but there is an error "driver data not ready may be empty" if my stack folder is moved to the util folder then the error disappears. What is the solution to keep the database path in an existing position? VDos and other files I put in the util folder but there is an error "driver data not ready may be empty" if my stack folder is moved to the util folder then the error disappears. What is the solution to keep the database path in an existing position?
thanks

```
@ECHO OFF

rem This is essentialy the autoexec.bat of DOS.
rem Only one additional vDos specific command is available: USE.

rem At startup only z: (bootdisk/command.com) is known by DOS.
rem So first you assign one or more DOS driveletters to Windows directories.
rem Use <driveletter:> <Windows directory>
rem Files/directories that don't confirm to the DOS 8.3 filenaming are hidden (as it should).

rem To just use the vDos working directory as c:
USE C: C:\Util\
c:
cd CAMUS.EXE
CAMUS.EXE

rem switch from z: to c:
C:
exit
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8lIW.jpg)

Comment: You will have to "cd" to the Utils folder, not the exe

Comment: @HansKeﬆing , `cd C:\UTIL\` I made it like this is still an error

Comment: I don't know Camus, but I assume it either uses a config file or a command line parameter to point it to it's datafile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://sourceforge.net/p/vdos/discussion/general/thread/98b18428/)!

```
@ECHO OFF

rem This is essentialy the autoexec.bat of DOS.
rem Only one additional vDos specific command is available: USE.

rem At startup only z: (bootdisk/command.com) is known by DOS.
rem So first you assign one or more DOS driveletters to Windows directories.
rem Use <driveletter:> <Windows directory>
rem Files/directories that don't confirm to the DOS 8.3 filenaming are hidden (as it should).

rem To just use the vDos working directory as c:
USE C: C:\
c:
cd C:\UTIL
CAMUS.EXE

rem switch from z: to c:
C:
exit
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).